# How do I search for a particular string in a large text block in python and get the next value?

Tags: python, regex, linux

I'm new to Programming and Python. I have searched a lot but have not been able to find the solution.

I'm running below command to get a session_timeout value from my application

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {} sudo /var/application/mycommand | grep session_  timeout".format(ip)
```

And the output is something like this

```
WARNING:THIS IS NDA, THIS NDA, THIS NDA
Use Policy and Information Protection Policy; access may be monitored
and logged, to the extent permitted by law, in accordance with 
policies.  Unauthorized use may result in termination of your access,
disciplinary action and/or civil and criminal penalties

session_timeout: 65526
```

This is what I have comeup so far

```
try:
        out = subprocess.check_output(
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {} sudo /var/application/mycommand | grep session_  timeout".format(ip)
            stderr=STDOUT,
            shell=True,
            universal_newlines=True,).strip()
        s = out.read().replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n')
        lines = s.split('\n')
        print(lines)
```

But this doesn't get me what I want. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: If that output is indicative of what will get you can simply match `\d+`. Alternatively, you could split the string on `"session timeout: "` and take the second of the two resulting strings  (`"65526\n"` in your example).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match `session_timeout:`  before the number, which you can match with `\d+`.

```
import re

data = '''WARNING:THIS IS NDA, THIS NDA, THIS NDA
Use Policy and Information Protection Policy; access may be monitored
and logged, to the extent permitted by law, in accordance with 
policies.  Unauthorized use may result in termination of your access,
disciplinary action and/or civil and criminal penalties

session_timeout: 65526
'''
match = re.search(r'(?<=session_timeout: )\d+', data)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
```

Comment: Holy shit. I just tried this and worked! Thank you for including the link. I will read through that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tried `grep`, what about this ?

```
cat << EOF | grep -Po 'session_timeout: \K.*'
WARNING:THIS IS NDA, THIS NDA, THIS NDA
Use Policy and Information Protection Policy; access may be monitored
and logged, to the extent permitted by law, in accordance with 
policies.  Unauthorized use may result in termination of your access,
disciplinary action and/or civil and criminal penalties

session_timeout: 65526
EOF
# Output : 65526
```

Comment: `\K` is not supported by Python's standard regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for this use-case are trivial. You just need to find the index of the constant string 'session_timeout:' then extract what follows.

```
    ST = 'session_timeout:'
    try:
        i = data.index(ST)
        print(data[i+len(ST):].strip())
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

**Output:**

```
65526
```

**Note:**

For the sample data shown in the question, this solution is significantly faster than using a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

> *"How do I search for a particular string in a large text block in python and get the next value?*
>
> *I'm new to Programming and Python. I have searched a lot but have not been able to find the solution. ..."*

Technically, a *regular expression pattern* isn't required for this.

Regardless, here is the documentation for the *re* module.
*[re – Functions — Regular expression operations — Python 3.11.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#functions)*.

> *"... I'm running below command to get a session_timeout value from my application ..."*

If it is always going to be the last value within the text, just parse at the last space character.

```py
s = s[s.rfind(' ') + 1:]
```

If you did want to isolate the value following *"session_timeout"* specifically, use the following pattern.
The *[re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.search)* method will return the first match.

```
s = re.search('session_timeout:(.+)$', s).group(1).lstrip()
```

Output

```
65526
```